# How to exclude an artifact, which is used as transitive by several other dependencies, in one place

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml, dependency-management

Our project has migrated from `log4j` to `log4j2`. However, other projects, which our project depends on, are still  using `log4j`.
If I want to exclude `log4j` with `exclusions`, I need to add more than **10** exclusions on a single `pom.xml` and it is not practical.

**Question**: is there any way to say, it does not matter, from where it comes, exclude `log4j` from my project. It is like the exact opposite of adding dependency.

Comment: do you have control over these other projects?

Comment: theoretically yes but they belong to other departments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This not possible at POM level, as stated by [official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)

> **Why exclusions are made on a per-dependency basis, rather than at the POM level**
>
> This is mainly done to be sure the dependency graph is predictable, and to keep inheritance effects from excluding a dependency that should not be excluded. If you get to the method of last resort and have to put in an exclusion, you should be absolutely certain which of your dependencies is bringing in that unwanted transitive dependency.

If you have control over the other projects you depend on, then the concerned dependency should be declared as `optional`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Optional doesn't affect the project itself (it will keep on having this dependency) but it will not be considered as transitive dependency by dependent projects (hence, you will have the choice to ignore it or to re-declare it, if needed).

As from [official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

> Optional dependencies - If project Y depends on project Z, the owner of project Y can mark project Z as an optional dependency, using the "optional" element. When project X depends on project Y, X will depend only on Y and not on Y's optional dependency Z. The owner of project X may then explicitly add a dependency on Z, at her option. (It may be helpful to think of optional dependencies as "excluded by default.").

---

Afterwards, if you really want to make sure that the concerned dependency is not brought in by any dependency transitively, you could configure your build to ban it (the build would fail whenever the concerned dependency appears) using the [Maven Enforcer Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/) and its [bannedDependencies](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/bannedDependencies.html) rule.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry, I cannot upvote because of my poor reputation.

Comment: @drJava nice memory! :)